# Symfony custom parameter fails when using composer

Tags: symfony, parameters, composer-php

I am having trouble with symfony parameters. In `config_dev.yml` I have this line:

```
swiftmailer:
delivery_address: "%support_email%"
```

and now I want to add the parameter `support_email` to the `parameters.yml`

```
parameters:
   support_email: test@test.com
```

Now if I run `composer update` I get this error:

```
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
  You have requested a non-existent parameter "support_email".
```

What can I do to handle this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony does read the file parameters.yml.dist then build the parameters.yml, and removes parameters that are not defined in the .dist.

Just add this line in parameters.yml.dist:

```
parameters:
    [...]
    support_email: you@company.com
```